# Spring Security REST Application - Wrong content-type and missing headers

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Inside a REST application (using Spring 4.2.2, Spring-Security 4.0.3, Spring-Security oAuth2 2.0.8) we notice a strange behaviour, sometimes (once out of 10/20 requests) the response does not contain all the headers (for example Content-length) and also the content-type is wrong (text/plain instead of application/json).

When everything works as expected we get following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2015 14:26:00 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION, CONTENT-TYPE
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1571
Connection: close
```

However, when we have the "problem" we receive only:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2015 14:23:36 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION, CONTENT-TYPE
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

The problem happens both on our servers, where the application runs on Tomcat (6 and 7) behind an Apache HTTPD server (with mod_ajp) and on the development environment where we use VMware vFabric tc Server.
We experienced this problem on all the major browser and also using curl.

We noticed that the problem seems to arize only when "parallel" requests are sent to the server. Indeed, if we call hundreds time the same service (for example with a shell script) the problem does not happens. Instead if during the same test we also perform other requests (from the browser) it appears.

Could the problem been caused by some libraries conflict? We use Jackson 2.x inside the application but I've seen that Spring Security oAuth still references Jackson 1.x (but it said that it works with both) => in the war file we have both libraries.
Or could be a problem with the Message converver? Or what else?

Thanks a lot for your help and support.

Best regards

Comment: Errors happen due to parallel requests? It looks like your backend service has a race condition somewhere. To prove wrong your assumption that there is a version clash with jackson you should replace your domain logic with a mock and run your tests again.

Comment: What I see from the trace logs is that in all the cases the methods execution, both of our services and of Spring, ends normally without any warning or special notice.

Comment: That doesn't mean that there isn't a race condition. You should mock out components of your application step by step and repeat your test to narrow down the root cause. Faulty responses generate a plain text response. How does it look like?

Comment: The body of the response in the problematic cases looks exactly the same as in the the successful cases (same JSON element)

Comment: We updated to the latest Spring and Spring Security (5.x version) but we still have this problem. Randomly the responses have missing headers.
Enabling debug log for Spring classes appears for example: "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK, headers={}" instead of "headers={masked}". 
The problem appears really randomly: i can call the same rest method multiple time and get once a correct response and once a "wrong" one. I really don't know where to investigate...